# Need to find average and number of repetitions of column

Tags: sql, counter, average, postgresql-9.5

I have an SQL sentence :

```
SELECT application.id,title,url,company.name AS company_name,package_name,ranking,date,platform,country.name AS country_name,collection.name AS collection_name,category.name AS category_name FROM application
JOIN application_history ON application_history.application_id = application.id
JOIN company ON application.company_id = company.id
JOIN country ON application_history.country_id = country.id
JOIN collection ON application_history.collection_id = collection.id
JOIN category ON application_history.category_id = category.id
WHERE application.platform=0
AND country.name ='CZ'
AND collection.name='topfreeapplications'
AND category.name='UTILITIES'
AND application_history.ranking <= 10
AND date::date BETWEEN date (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 month') AND CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY application_history.ranking ASC
```

It produces this result :

[image]

I'd like to add both a column average ranking for a given package, and a column number of appearances, which would count the number a package appears in the list. I'd also like to Group results by package_name, so that I don't have redundancies.

So far, I've tried to add a GROUP BY By clause before the ORDER BY :

```
GROUP BY package_name
```

But it returns me an error :

```
column "application.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

If I add each and every column it asks me for, it doesn't work.
I have also tried to count the number of package names, by adding after the SELECT :

```
COUNT(package_name) AS count
```

It produces a similar error.

How could I get the result I'm looking for ? Should I make two queries instead, or is it possible to get everything at once ?
I precise I have looked at other answers on S.O, but none of them tries to make the COUNT on a "produced" column.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit :**

Here is the result I expected at first :

[image]

Although Gordon's advice didn't give me the proper result it put me on the good track, when I read this :
From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) : *"Unlike regular aggregate functions, use of a window function does not cause rows to become grouped into a single output row."*

So I came back to using COUNT and AVG alone. My problem was that I wanted to display the ranking column and date to check whether things were right. But putting these column into the Select prevented the GROUP BY to work as expected, as mentioned by Jarlh in the comments.

The working query :

```
SELECT application.id,title,url,company.name AS company_name,package_name,platform,country.name AS country_name,collection.name AS collection_name,category.name AS category_name, 
    COUNT(package_name) AS count, AVG(application_history.ranking) AS avg
    FROM application
    JOIN application_history ON application_history.application_id = application.id
    JOIN company ON application.company_id = company.id
    JOIN country ON application_history.country_id = country.id
    JOIN collection ON application_history.collection_id = collection.id
    JOIN category ON application_history.category_id = category.id
    WHERE application.platform=0
    AND country.name ='CZ'
    AND collection.name='topfreeapplications'
    AND category.name='UTILITIES'
    AND application_history.ranking <= 10
    AND date::date BETWEEN date (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 month') AND CURRENT_DATE
    GROUP BY package_name,application.id,company.name,country.name,collection.name,category.name
    ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: General GROUP BY tip: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: So if I understand correctly, that would mean I'd have to make two queries ?

Comment: @Stanislasdrg: You have shown what your result looks like now. Now please also show how you want it to look instead. This will make it much easier for us to understand what you want exactly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, well, Gordon got it right in the first place, so I guess the question was explicit enough. Why the downvote then ? Window functions aren't exactly what a pg newcomer should be aware of. Furthermore, it's part of pg advanced features in the docs.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I also did notice that you put effort in your request, so I see no reason for a downvote. You are right, Gordon got it right. I on the other hand wasn't sure what it was exactly what you were looking for, so I couldn't help. The phrase "I'd also like to group results by package_name, so that I don't have redundancies." for example made me think you wanted less rows. As a general rule: It really helps to show the expected result with SQL requests. There are many requests here on SO where the people keep guessing and guessing what's being asked ;-)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. You're right, in the sense that I didn't want redundancies, but answers put me on the good track. Will update the question with the first expected results. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want window/analytic functions.  The following adds two columns, one for the count of rows for each package and the other an average ranking for them:

```
SELECT application.id, title, url, company.name AS company_name, package_name, 
       ranking, date, platform, country.name AS country_name,
       collection.name AS collection_name, category.name AS category_name,
       count(*) over (partition by package_name) as count,
       avg(ranking) over (partition by package_name) as avg_package_ranking
FROM application . . .
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Never heard about the window/analytic functions, I'll look into it right away :-)

Comment: @Stanislasdrg: check out the tutorial in the Postgres manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Thank to both of you, it finally worked ! And was exactly what I was looking for.